# Pasar variable en laravel a sweetalert2

Tags: sweetalert2

Necesito pasar desde mi controlador un campo de la bbdd para que lo imprima en un modal de sweetalert pero no consigo que me lo imprima

El campo lo capturo a través de una condición:

```
    $nombre_empleado = Empleado::where('codigo_empleado', $asistencia->codigo_empleado)->get('nombre');
```

Pero he intentado pasarlo a la vista para imprimirlo en swal y no funciona de ninguna de las maneras:

```
        return redirect()->route('home')
            ->with('store_result', 'nok')
            ->with('empleado', $nombre_empleado);
```

En swal he probado con y sin comillas, de mil maneras pero no acierto...

```
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Entrada registrada',
            html: 'Hora: ' + moment().format('HH:mm:ss') + '<br>' + ' empleado',
        })
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes recibir el valor que envias con el with asi:

```
@if(Session::has('empleado')) //nombre del campo de with, verificamos que exista
  <script>
    Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Entrada registrada',
            html: 'Hora: ' + moment().format('HH:mm:ss') + '<br>' + '{{ Session::get('empleado') }}', //obtenemos el valor del campo
        })
  </script>
@endif
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias